# Qt: Iterate over all top-level windows

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt

How can I iterate over all top-level windows (i.e. widgets which have `parent==0`) in my Qt4 application?

(Both C++ and Python examples are acceptable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()`.  Docs [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets).

Comment: @superbatfish There's lots of cool functionality in `QApplication` but it's never the first place you look...